# Laravel Model Delete Single Record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having trouble getting a chained query to work for deleting a single record in 2 different columns in the user model. On submit, I want to delete the user's record in `column A` and `column B` only, nothing else.

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('column_A')->delete()
    ->select('column_B')->delete()
    ->update([
        'column_A' => 'value',
    ]);
```

This actually deletes that user's entire record. I have also tried substituting select for value and then I'll get the error:

> calling delete() on string

Thanks!

Comment: Are you want to update column A and column B? I am little confused.

Comment: Well, update the values to ' '. Like Alexey has below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->update([
        'column_A' => '',
        'column_B' => ''
    ]);
```

I can use [`delete()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#deletes) only to delete whole rows, but not some information in that row.